# Change default applications in Lubuntu using configuration file

Tags: lubuntu, configuration, default-programs

In Lubuntu I can change the default applications using `Default applications for LXSession`. It saves the default applications in the configuraion file `/home/USER/.config/lxsession/Lubuntu/desktop.conf`.

Now, I'd like to change default applications by editing the `desktop.conf` file. So, I change/save the `desktop.conf` file or overwrite it with the one from another machine. But when I re-open `Default applications for LXSession`. it does not show the changes.

How can I change the default applications using the configuration file? Do I need to run a command after editing the file?